# Get and Setfocus of an element

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

What I am trying to do is get the last focus element before doing a refresh on my BO and set it back to the last focus value.

the idea is something like below:

```
//get last focus element
var x = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
//refresh my businessobject here
CallMethod();
//set the focus to my last element
FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(focusScope, x);
```

... but the problem here is after calling the refresh object method my "x" value got changed in the process.

Anyone experience this problem?

Comment: the problem is the "x" value gets changed after the CallMethod. Eventhough I only set it once. It's like getting the value of the first element of the focusScope.

Comment: My goal is to save the value of "x" so after doing a refresh in the business object, I can set the focus back to my last focus control before the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just assign `Keyboard.FocusedElement` because `Keyboard.FocusedElement` is a reference type.  So as soon as the Framework changes the `Keyboard.FocusedElement`, your copy changes.  You will need to find a new way to identify the control that had focus before the call or try and find a deep copy solution that works.

Comment: That is what I thought of happening. Do you have other other idea on how to achieve deep copy? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, deep copying is not easy in .NET.  Especially if it involves an object that has many reference and nested objects in it.  I've seen solutions that use serialization and deserialization, some use reflection, others use copy constructors for all the reference types within the object.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using deep copy here.  I would try other alternatives such as not remembering the object but maybe remembering the name of the control or something along those lines.

Comment: Actually, I will step back a little bit... I did a simple WPF program where it has 4 textbox and 1 button. So in my code behind and text2_textchanged event I assigned Keyboard.FocusedElement to my variable x and on my button_click - i had another call of Keyboard.FocusedElement assigned to y and then did an x.Focus() and it remembers the original value of x and it works... so I don't think it is reference type.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `Focus()` method??

```
//get focused element
UIElement x = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;

//refresh my businessobject here
CallMethod();

//set the focus to my last element
x.Focus();
```

or consider using `FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(focusScope)`...

Comment: In my CallMethod(), there is a function that whenever I refresh a BO then it will always set to the first element. So if I do the x.Focus() the "x" does not contain my last focus element anymore. Josh, hit it right on the ball that it is reference type. I will just do an extension method of deep copy to overcome this - but if anyone has better idea please let me know. THanks!